# Tesseract OCR - TIFFReadDirectory: Warning, Unknown field with tag 37724 (0x935c)

Tags: tesseract

Used Tesseract to analyze a .tif image and encountered the errors below. Tried to Google but did not get a definite answer. Has anyone experienced these before?

Command: `tesseract "source.tif" "destination" -l swe`

https://github.com/UB-Mannheim/tesseract/wiki

```
Tesseract Open Source OCR Engine v3.05.00dev with Leptonica
TIFFReadDirectory: Warning, Unknown field with tag 37724 (0x935c) encountered.
TIFFFetchNormalTag: Warning, Incompatible type for "RichTIFFIPTC"; tag ignored.
Page 1
TIFFReadDirectory: Warning, Unknown field with tag 37724 (0x935c) encountered.
TIFFFetchNormalTag: Warning, Incompatible type for "RichTIFFIPTC"; tag ignored.
```

Answer (score 0):

The warnings came from `libtiff` indicating discrepancies in the input TIFF image. They can be ignored, or use `quiet` option if you want to suppress them from printing to the console.

https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/FAQ#how-can-i-suppress-tesseract-info-line